# React giving a white screen

Tags: reactjs, electron

I' trying to create a react project in electronjs but I'm gettting a white screen. I have googled and tried many ways but I could not manage to get anything on the screen

Here is my index.html in public folder.

```
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <!--
          This HTML file is a template.
          If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.
    
          You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
          The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.
    
          To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
          To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
        -->
      </body>



here is index.js in src folder
``js
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run npm start or yarn start.
      To create a production bundle, use npm run build or yarn build.
    -->
  </body>`
here is app.js in src folderjs
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run npm start or yarn start.
      To create a production bundle, use npm run build or yarn build.
    -->
  </body>
``
```

Comment: That's not how `index.js` is supposed to be laid out in a react app.  You need to research how to create a basic react app (literally hundreds of sources to find) before asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @user16340489 Buddy, you seem to be new to StackOverflow. Try sending a public Codesandbox if you aren’t able to figure out anything. The thing you pasted in the question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Give [my Electron template](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/) a try. Or, if you are looking for something more minimal, you can [try this template](https://github.com/reZach/simple-electron-template).